# WordPress insert new user in wp_users

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to create a new user in wp_users table but neither wp_create_user nor wp_insert_user worked.
I'm trying in this way but no user is inserted.

```
$newUser = $wpdb->insert(
        'wp_users',
        array(
            'user_login' => $userRow->email,
            'user_pass' => $userRow->password,
            'user_nicename' => $userRow->firstname,
            'user_email' => $userRow->email,
            'user_url' => '',
            'user_registered' => $userRow->registration,
            'user_status' => 0,
            'display_name' => $userRow->firstname
        )
    );
    if(!$newUser) {
        echo '<script>alert("User has not been created.")</script>'; 
        return;
    }
```

Comment: there is no problem in your code. "$userRow->email" these are not getting any values. So it is not inserting into database

Comment: Yes I am curious what you see when you add `var_dump($userRow); wp_die();` to your function before trying to insert the new user to the DB. By looking at that dump you will know if you have the required data to create a new user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this to create user in WP

Make sure your variable has values

```
$username = $userRow->email;
$email    = $userRow->email;
$password = $userRow->password;

$user = wp_insert_user(array(
            'user_login'  =>  $username,
            'user_email'  =>  $email,
            'user_pass'   =>  $password,
        ));

    if( !is_wp_error( $user ) ){

    } else {
        // success message
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to print thease variables before insert code
$userRow->email, $userRow->password. Make sure thease variable cant be blank

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$WP_array = array (
    'user_login'    =>  'username',
    'user_email'    =>  'emailID',
    'user_pass'     =>  'Password',

) ;

$id = wp_insert_user( $WP_array ) ;
// if you want to add role to user
wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $id, 'role' => 'editor') ) ;
```